# linux string manipulaction

Tags: linux

I have a file that file contain following logs some times it changed but on part is there always FILE. i want to extract that file name up to .xls

```
cat /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log | awk '{print $10}'| sed 's/]//g'
```

when the filename are not space it is showing ok like in below log

```
 userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls
```

file but when the file name contains some space it fetch up to that space like

```
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week
```

but in PB case i need that file name in proper format..

Is there any solution for this

I want this output in space case::

```
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ \one\ \payout.xls
```

so that i can move that file to another location. If it not contain space then it only give the file name up to .xls.

```
Logs are ::::::::::::::::::::::::
INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9854798391] [FILE NAME: userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls] [MESSAGE: User not active] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9854803938] [FILE NAME: userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls] [MESSAGE: No channel user exist by this mobile number] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803493705] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain]
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803493706] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803493707] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803590276] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803590277] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803590802] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: NA] [FILE NAME: userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index] 
 INFO [main] (DirectPayOutErrorLog.java:113) -   :: [MSISDN: 9803594351] [FILE NAME: userList1305647896930_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls] [MESSAGE: user does not belong to specified domain]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*\[FILE NAME: \([^]]*\)].*/\1/p' /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log
```

It should not be necessary to "manually" escape the space, as long as you correctly quote the variable you use to store the file name each time you use it (assuming you're talking about a shell script).

If you want to act on each file name for each occurance, you can do something like this:

```
INPUT_FILE=/pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log
sed -n -e 's/.*\[FILE NAME: \([^]]*\)].*/\1/p' $INPUT_FILE | while read file ; do
  mv "$file" $SOME_DESTINATION
done
```

If you only want to act on each file once, you can easily add `sort -u` into this pipe:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*\[FILE NAME: \([^]]*\)].*/\1/p' $INPUT_FILE | sort -u | while read file ; do
  // do stuff with "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for support but if i tray to move this file then  foe PB case what i do. where it takes space.. userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls
userList1305647866843_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls
userList1305647896930_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week one payout.xls   how can i Move the porticular using this file name

Comment: @Sunil, if you mean move the file with `mv` then you just need to surround the filename with quotes and it will be treated as one name.

Comment: @Sunil: the code I posted works with files containing spaces as well, try it.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
$ cut -s -f12,13,14 -d " " --output-delimiter='\ ' log | sed 's#\].*$##'

userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls
userList1305631236859_AS_ALL_DIST_ALL_ETOPUP_1305631236859.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647880920_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
userList1305647896930_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_Week\ one\ payout.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames don't contain ']', this is all you need:

```
sed 's/.*FILE NAME: //;s/].*//;s/ /\\ /g' logfile
```

Else search for `] [MESSAGE:`.